# TSA approved keycard luggage locks that shows if it's been opened?

Tags: luggage, security, tsa

I want to get those keycard TSA approved luggage locks but I can't find a keycard one that has some method to notify you if it's been opened. All the you-can-know-if-opened locks that I can find are only opened by keys or codes...does anybody make a TSA approved KEYCARD lock like the one I need?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be no at the present time.  The keycards appear to be designed for those who want convenience, whereas the locks that notify you if your luggage has been opened tend to be manufactured and sold by more security conscious people.  I'm guessing that the manufacturers of the devices don't think there's a significant overlap between the two markets unfortunately.